# Change Parent url from iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, parent

Need help with a simple problem! which has the following criteria:

1) click on images link in iframe changes Parent page, click on another iframe image link changes Parent to another page (see below).

It may sound simple but I'm being googled it for days now and looked over many forums. 
Code can be in html css or js, but please keep any answers simple as possible and post a full working example to work as I'm new to coding or recode the test site: http://www.howiepotter.com/parent.html

[image]

Comment: can you please post the code you're currently using, in addition to the link you provided?

Comment: You need to name the parent and use the `target` attribute. Also spend some time reading the documentation. Or even just searching in Google.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the URL of the "parent" frame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361479/how-do-i-change-the-url-of-the-parent-frame)

Comment: If you are using JavaScript for this, you can use `window.open("the-new-url-goes-here", "_top")`.

Answer (score 91):

http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/a/target

> "_top"
>
> loads content in the top-level frameset (in effect, the whole browser
>   window), no matter how many nested levels down the current frame is
>   located

```
<a href="page" target="_top">Replace parent url!</a>
```

Comment: while the question was for JS, this is MUCH easier for my current needs.

Comment: could even use target="_parent"

Comment: What if I deleted this answer of mine?

Comment: why would you @biziclop ?

Comment: @Pixelomo: too much upvote for a too simple answer. :)

Comment: and how can I stop it?

Comment: @DipanshuMahla: Stop what?

Comment: How can we stop iframe from doing that? @biziclop

Comment: @DipanshuMahla: We can't, and I'm glad we can't.

Answer (score 42):

Change your link from this:

```
<a href="link-here.html">
```

To this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="top.window.location.href='yourURL';">
```

If you want, you could just put the `onclick` handler on the image instead and get rid of the anchor.

Note that this is not the correct place to have javascript (handlers should be bound from a .js file, not in markup), but i get the feeling you are looking for a surgical answer and don't care much for best practices.

edit: as Victor Nicollet pointed out, this will throw a security exception if your iframe and parent page do not share domains. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: This. Also, keep in mind that the frame and the page containing the frame must come from the same domain for this to work.

Comment: Note that _Same origin policy_ is not a blocker as long as the `iframe` is sanboxed correctly, and/or the navigation is triggered by a user gesture. Try this: https://real-archer.glitch.me

Comment: @Alireza what do you mean by "sandboxed correctly"?

Answer (score 12):

In my case I used the following

```
if (window.self !== window.top) { // checking if it is an iframe
  window.parent.location.href = websiteUrl;
} else {
  window.location.href = websiteUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case @biziclop decides to delete his answer as he seems to be threatening to do in the comments, here's his answer again which is very useful:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/a/target

> "_top"
>
> loads content in the top-level frameset (in effect, the whole browser
>   window), no matter how many nested levels down the current frame is
>   located

```
<a href="page" target="_top">Replace parent url!</a>
```