# How to change iframe parent (top) location to url relative to iframe in IE with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-browser, relative-path

**exampleA.com**

```
<iframe src="http://exampleB.com/">
```

**exampleB.com**

```
<button onclick="top.location='/test'">Test</button>
```

In Chrome (and I assume most browsers), clicking on the "Test" button inside the iframe changes the parent page to `exampleB.com/test`,  but in IE it sets the location relative to the parent URL (`exampleA.com/test`).

**How can I make the test button work in all browsers with a URL relative to the iframe?**

---

**NOTE**:

This can be done in HTML like:  `<a href="/test" target="top">Test</a>` as mentioned in the comments. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207900/change-parent-url-from-iframe/11208032).

However, I need(ed) a JavaScript-based solution for the parent location to be changed in reaction to an event, rather than a mouse click.

Comment: Why not use a link? `<a href="/test" target="top">Test</a>` should resolve the `href` to the current frame, then navigate the parent to it. If that doesn't work `<a href="/test" onclick="top.location=this.href;return false;">Test</a>` should.

Comment: my example is much simpler than the actual code in production.  There is no button.  The parent page is changed automatically in response to an ajax call from within the iframe which generates a url fragment dynamically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like I've answered my own question...

**exampleB.com**

```
<button onclick="topLocation('/test')">Test</button>

<script>
var topLocation = function(url) {
    // make sure its a relative url
    if (url[0] === '/' && url[1] !== '/'){
        // x-broswer window.location.origin 
        if (!window.location.origin) window.location.origin = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host;
        window.top.location = window.location.origin + url;
    } else {
        window.top.location = url;
    }
}
</script>
```

I found the code to get the base url (window.location.origin) from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6167979/363701])

Comment: Kinda old, but I found this solution using HTML property `target` http://stackoverflow.com/a/11208032/552669

Comment: I'll update the question to make it more clear and link to this answer, but I needed a JavaScript based-solution to change the url based on an event. As such the `<a href="/test" target="top">` would not work