# opening a javascript url outside of facebook frame app

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe

I have built a facebook app that has a  menu for a navigation and I want to be able to open my links outside of the iframe app.  is this possible?  I am using this and it loads inside the iframe but I cant get it to load outside of the iframe (parent window).

```
<select ONCHANGE="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
        <option>Shop our entire store..</option>
        <option>Collections</option>
        <option>-------------------------</option>
        <option value="link.html">Mid Spring 2013</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207900/change-parent-url-from-iframe

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this still works, but I remember you used to do

```
top.location = "http://www.example/com"
```

back in the day

Comment: Way to go Dave!  you made my day! You rock!