# iframes: link changes frame instead of page

Tags: iframe

Our page has two iframes, clicking on a link in one only changes that one frame instead of the entire page. How can that link be made to change the entire page? How can that be an id that can be targeted?

Comment: What do you mean by targeting an ID?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Parent url from iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207900/change-parent-url-from-iframe)